# How do I populate the SharePointIds property on Drive and DriveItem objects?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using the Graph API NuGet package, how do I populate the SharePointIds property.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public async Task<Drive> RetrieveOneDriveForUserAsync(string userId)
    {
        return await _graphClient.Users[userId].Drive.Request().GetAsync();
    }
```

The "SharepointIds" property is always NULL

EDIT:

NOTE:  This is NOT for personal OneDrive items.  This is for Group OneDrive items.

This is the documentation for the Drive object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/drive?view=graph-rest-1.0

This is the documentation for the DriveItem object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

This is the documentation for the SharepointIds object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepointids?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 2):

The SharePointIds object applies to **an item** stored in a SharePoint Site.

```
_graphClient.Users[userId].Drive.Items[itemId].Request().Select("sharepointids").GetAsync();
```

(Folders are an item, so you can get the Ids for Root.)

```
_graphClient.Users[userId].Drive.Root.Request().Select("sharepointids").GetAsync();
```

Comment: The important point that I didn't realize is that you have to explicitly $select sharepointIds or it doesn't come back.

Comment: Yeah, the idea behind `sharepointIds` is that they're only needed if you're essentially interoping between data from the older APIs and the new APIs. If your app only deals with Graph you shouldn't need the `sharepointIds` and so they don't come back by default. Our documentation is obviously lacking in this regard though... it should probably call out fields that are not returned by default.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The problem is if I use this I ONLY get 'sharepointids' populated.  The rest of the properties are null.  _graphClient.Groups[groupId].Drive.Root.Search("").Request().Select("sharepointids").GetAsync();

Comment: You did know that you can add multiple attributes to the Select method, right?